# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TabularInLine'

Tags: django

What could be the problem in this code I am trying to add Cart in an e-commerce page and it return with an Attribute Error

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Cart, CartItem

class CartItemInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CartItem

class CartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CartItemInLine
    ]
    class Meta:
        model = Cart

admin.site.register(Cart, CartAdmin)
```

Comment: Post your error stack trace.

Comment: The name of the class is `TabularInline`, not `TabularInLine` (the `L` should not be capital).

Comment: @xyres thank you for the heads up. This was also the case with `StackedInline` (I was writing it the wrong way, with a capital `L`)